# how obtain directory files info

Tags: shell-script, solaris

I have the need to get information about a specific directory, basically I need to know the correlation between small, medium and big files.

I came up with this:

```
for i in K M G; do
  printf $i
  du -h /usr/opt |
    awk '{print $1}' |
    grep ${i}$ |
    wc -l
done | tee /stat.out
```

from the result then I add all numbers and subtract the total to obtain the number of files under 1k. ( I presume we have a lot of them since it's source files)

Anyway, this way is good for small directories, I actually have a very big one (expecting over 1Tera) and no idea of the files distribution.
I need to copy all these files to a private storage and need to give a estimate time on the copy.

I was thinking on the line of doing something as this:

```
find pwd |xargs ls -lph |awk '{print $5}'
```

But I miss what I should put after or if I should take another approach.

Comment: is there a reason you aren't using `find ... -size -1k`?

Comment: that forces me to do as well several passes for each size that I need. which takes ages. :/
I would like to to it in one pass of find instead of 4. that's why I'm using find with ls, this way the bytes are shown as numbers, and the rest with numbers and size: examples 123K, 84M, etc.

Comment: Just collect the data in one `ls`, and process the list of sizes? Could even do fancy histograms and other pretty images...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use GNU find (non-embedded Linux or Cygwin), make `find` print the file sizes and post-process the output with `awk` to sort each size into a category, `sort` and `uniq` to group by categories, and `awk` or `sed` to pretty-print the result. Something like:

```
find /usr/opt -type f -printf '%s\n' |
awk '{
    if ($1 ~ /^[2-9]......../) { print "3 G" }
    else if ($1 >= 1073741824) {  print "3 G" }
    else if ($1 >= 1048576) { print "2 M" }
    else if ($1 >= 1024) { print "1 k" }
    else if ($1 >= 1) { print "0" }
}' |
sort | uniq -c |
awk '{print $1 " files are in the " $3 "B range"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I came up with was to resort to a awk script.

```
{
if ( substr( $5, length($5), length($5) ) == "K" ) {
        totK++;
        totKsize = totKsize + substr($5, 0, length($5) - 1 );}
else if ( substr( $5, length($5), length($5) ) == "M" ) {
        totM++;
        totMsize = totMsize + substr($5, 0, length($5) - 1 );}
else if ( substr( $5, length($5), length($5) ) == "G" ) {
        totG++;
        totGsize = totGsize + substr($5, 0, length($5) - 1 );}
else  {
        totB++;
        totBsize=totBsize + $5; }
}
END{
print "NR of files less than 1k => " totB " total " totBsize;
print "NR of files less than 1M => " totK " total " totKsize;
print "NR of files less than 1G => " totM " total " totMsize;
print "NR of files bigger than 1G => " totG " total " totGsize;
}
```

And execute the pass like this:

```
find . -type f |xargs ls -lh |/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -f count_files.awk
```